# OS X Contacts (Mountain Lion) with CardDav - "CoreDAVHTTPStatusErrorDomain error 500"

Tags: macos, contacts

I've recently setup a CardDav account with a hosted [Atmail Cloud](http://atmailcloud.com) account. It works perfectly on iOS, and seems to pull in some of the contacts, however every time Contacts re-syncs I am getting the following error:

```
    9/20/12 5:19:24.622 PM Contacts[785]: [CardDAVPlugin-ERROR] -_handleCompletedAction: Error Domain=CoreDAVHTTPStatusErrorDomain Code=500 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (CoreDAVHTTPStatusErrorDomain error 500.)" UserInfo=0x7ff1a6409cb0 {CoreDAVHTTPHeaders=<CFBasicHash 0x7ff1a61475b0 [0x7fff73a56fd0]>{type = immutable dict, count = 8,
entries =>
    0 : Case Insensitive Key: Server = <CFString 0x7ff1a66096c0 [0x7fff73a56fd0]>{contents = "Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)"}
    1 : Case Insensitive Key: X-Powered-By = <CFString 0x7ff1a64bc030 [0x7fff73a56fd0]>{contents = "PHP/5.3.3"}
    2 : Case Insensitive Key: Connection = <CFString 0x7ff1a64aa4a0 [0x7fff73a56fd0]>{contents = "close"}
    3 : Case Insensitive Key: Content-Type = <CFString 0x7ff1a661ccb0 [0x7fff73a56fd0]>{contents = "application/xml; charset=utf-8"}
    6 : Case Insensitive Key: Date = <CFString 0x7ff1a4efb270 [0x7fff73a56fd0]>{contents = "Thu, 20 Sep 2012 21:19:24 GMT"}
    8 : Case Insensitive Key: Content-Encoding = <CFString 0x7ff1a64a7220 [0x7fff73a56fd0]>{contents = "gzip"}
    10 : Case Insensitive Key: Content-Length = <CFString 0x7ff1a6149f80 [0x7fff73a56fd0]>{contents = "187"}
    12 : Case Insensitive Key: Vary = <CFString 0x7ff1a665dd70 [0x7fff73a56fd0]>{contents = "Accept-Encoding"}
}
}
```

Is this a problem with the CardDav server or Contacts? Anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: Effectively I used a Zimbra server connection since years and the address sync worked fine until we upgraded 2 Macs to recent apple version 10.8.2. For the others ones we stopped upgrading until issue would be solved. Our iphones 4, 4S continued working fine without apple cloud, but now a new iphone 5 shows same problems. I consider it is a voluntary change in operations system pushing third party server services services out off the game to push the cloud foreword. But such measure does not increase user confidence. Apple, remember your strenths and remind yourself why microsoft lost market p

Answer (score 1):

The response says the the error is when communicating with the 3rd party server (since the Mac isn't CentOS obviously) and that there was an error on the server side (type 500)

The [5xx range of HTTP response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) codes are for server side errors, basically there was an error, we couldn't do anything and we are closing the connection.

Comment: Think it's about server too. Maybe about configuration.